# What is the "pixel refresh" feature on the Panasonic Lumix DMC-G85?

Tags: panasonic-lumix

On my Panasonic Lumix DMC-G85, under the **Tools** menu, there's a **Pixel Refresh** option. When I select this, a "*Start Processing*?" prompt appears, with `Yes` and `No` options. The built-in "help" information for the camera describes the feature as follows:

> Perform optimization of imaging device and image processing

A few questions come to mind, as this verbiage is rather vague:

- What exactly does this mean, in plain English?
- Should I run this, and if so, how often should I run it?
- How long does it take to run?
- Is there any harm in running **Pixel Refresh** repeatedly?

Comment: I'm guessing it's equivalent to pixel mapping feature of other cameras to find dead sensels and dust.